# Treat missing rows as having 0 data

Tags: sql, hive

Suppose I have a table describing workers' contribution to projects

```
project worker contribution
1       1      2
1       2      3
2       1      4
```

To compute the worker impact, I can do

```
select t.project, t.worker, t.contribution, p.total, 
       t.contribution / p.total as relative 
from my_table t
join (select project, sum(contribution) as total
      from my_table group by project) p
on t.project = p.project
```

to get `new_table`

```
project worker contribution total relative
1       1      1            5     .2
1       2      4            5     .8
2       1      4            4     1
```

if I now compute the average relative contribution using

```
select worker, avg(relative) as avg_rel
from new_table group by worker
```

I will see

```
worker avg_rel
1      .6
2      .8
```

which disregards the 0 contribution of worker `2` to project `2`.

How do I take that into account?
I.e., I want to get

```
worker avg_rel
1      .6
2      .4
```

as if the original table also included the line

```
2       2      0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your first table does not contain the row "2 2 0" (at least as the question states it). Otherwise, I would think it should also appear in the result of your first select statement. And: is the result of the first select what you refer to later as `new_table`?

Comment: @FrankPl: yes, there is no such line, but I want the result as if it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this will work in Hive, but here is a SQL solution:

```
select w.worker, avg(coalesce(t.relative, 0.0)) as avg_rel
from (select distinct project from my_table) p cross join
     (select distinct worker from my_table) w left outer join
     my_table t
     on t.project = p.project and t.worker = w.worker
group by w.worker;
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you use a left outer join like this? Maybe join this with a list of workers?

```
select t.project, t.worker, t.contribution, p.total, 
   case when coalesce(p.total, 0) = 0 then 0 else t.contribution / p.total end as relative 
from my_table t
full
outer
join ( select distinct worker
         from my_table
       ) w
on t.worker = w.worker
join (select project, sum(contribution) as total
  from my_table group by project) p
on t.project = p.project
```

Comment: I think this outer join is identical to the inner join because there is always a match

Comment: still not good. the other answer worked though (still +1 because I learned something from your answer, thanks)